# Is there a function in R that can round down OR up to an integer?

Tags: r

Wondering if there an exists a function that can round a number up or down as I noticed that

```
as.integer(5.99999)
```

gives me 5, so it looks like as.integer coerces a numeric to an integer by dropping any number after the decimal place. Thank you!

Comment: See `floor` and `ceiling`.

Comment: Rounding down is known as flooring, and ceiling is a number rounded up. I don't know r, but try searching for those terms.

Comment: They all share the same help page, so `?round`, or `?floor`, `?ceiling` tells you everything you need.

Comment: For future reference, you can also check the "See Also" section of the help, as it often points to related functions. In the case of `as.integer`, the help file (run `?as.integer` to see the help) See Also section has a link to the help page for `round`, `ceiling` and `floor`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `round()` function works great. You can do the following to get a result of 6:

```
as.integer(round(5.99999))
```

If you want it to round up or down, use the `ceiling()` or `floor()` functions, respectively, in place of the `round()` function. Ex:

```
as.integer(ceiling(5.9999))
```

Comment: Careful, `round()` rounds to the nearest **even** number.  So both `1.5` and `2.5` get rounded to `2` but `3.5` gets rounded to `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some remarks to the answer from Sescopeland.

Everyone must be careful when using the `round()` function since it does not do what many people expect to do.

The function precisely returns the closest EVEN numbers!
For example,
`round(1.5)` would produce `2`
but also `round(2.5)` would produce `2` as well!

Please check out the `Details` section of the `?round()`.